# Is there a way to raise the monthly responses independently from Limesurvey subscription?

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to create an independent entity where I can host over 25 responses/month?

Comment: Besides [paying them](https://www.limesurvey.org/en/pricing)?

Comment: I believe you can just self-host LimeSurvey, [get it here](https://community.limesurvey.org/downloads/).